# Failed to call connect for MifareUltralight

Tags: java, android, nfc, mifare

I'm trying to read from an NFC-Tag (Type MiFare Ultralight). The aim is to read the whole tag and write it to an file.

Even though this might not seem like the most obvious scenario, I would neep your help:

When calling the `connect` method of my `MifareUltralight`-Tag instance i always get an `IOException`

The important part of the code:

```
....
MifareUltralight mf = MifareUltralight.get(tagFromIntent);
byte[] mfContents = new byte[64];
Log.v("Door-LOG", "TRY reading");
try {
    mf.connect();Log.v("Door-LOG", "connect");
    byte[] p1 = mf.readPages(0);Log.v("Door-LOG", "p1");
    byte[] p2 = mf.readPages(4);Log.v("Door-LOG", "p2");
    byte[] p3 = mf.readPages(8);Log.v("Door-LOG", "p3");
    byte[] p4 = mf.readPages(12);Log.v("Door-LOG", "p4");

    int offset = 0;
    System.arraycopy(p1, 0, mfContents, offset, p1.length); offset += p1.length;
    System.arraycopy(p2, 0, mfContents, offset, p2.length); offset += p2.length;
    System.arraycopy(p3, 0, mfContents, offset, p3.length); offset += p3.length;
    System.arraycopy(p4, 0, mfContents, offset, p4.length);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Door-LOG", "IOException while reading MifareUltralight message...",e);
    return;
} finally {
    if (mf != null) {
        try {
            mf.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("Door-LOG", "Failed Closing");
        }
    }
}
```

And the Exception Trace is:

```
java.io.IOException
        at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.connect(BasicTagTechnology.java)
        at android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight.connect(MifareUltralight.java)
        at eu.expandable.NFCTest.Main.readMifareUltralight(Main.java:199)
        at eu.expandable.NFCTest.Main.handleIntent(Main.java:188)
        at eu.expandable.NFCTest.Main.onCreate(Main.java:62)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I really count on you guys to help me getting along. Many Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you put the tag in range of the reader just the moment before that code is executed and that the tag is still in range when you try to connect, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right @MichaelRoland

Comment: What message does the `IOException` contain? Is it a `TagLostException`?

Comment: Well that was to easy.  I'll do it later this evening

Comment: Thanks Le_Morri ! Your question gave me a solution. I'm able to read payload. Thank You again.